# Cisco Route-Map Multiple ACL Match (Logical AND)

Tags: cisco, access-control-list, routing

I'm having difficulty to configure a route-map with multiple matches in AND operation.
The issue is, both match criteria are against ACL, but different ACL.

What I want to do is

```
route-map TEST permit 10
  match ip address 100
  match ip address 110
  set vrf TESTVRF
```

I was expecting above to be AND operation for the match requirement.

However, when I issue show run, it becomes

```
route-map TEST permit 10
  match ip address 100 110
  set vrf TESTVRF
```

which is an OR operation by Cisco syntax.

The question is, how can I do multiple ACL match in AND operation for route-map?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way in my opinion is to setup an `access-list` with all the matches you need and put that in the route-map.

**EDIT**

**Disclaimer**: I'm just guessing here.

You can try this, assuming `access-list 100` for sources and `access-list 110` for destinations:

Here you revert the logic of the `access-lists`:

```
access-list 100 deny ip 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 any
access-list 100 permit any

access-list 110 deny ip any 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
access-list 110 permit any
```

and then use `deny` on your `route-map` (so if the `access-list` **permits**, then the rule **fails**):

```
route-map TEST deny 10
   match ip address 100
route-map TEST deny 20
   match ip address 110
route-map TEST permit 30
   set vrf TESTVRF
```

The logic behind this is:

```
if source_address is not 10.0.0.0/24 {
    fail
} else {
    if destination_address is not 192.168.0.0/24 {
        fail
    } else {
        set vrf TESTVRF
    }
}
```

Basically it checks **first** if source is permitted (via `access-list 100`), if permitted **then** it checks if destination is permitted (`access-list 101`), at last if **BOTH** are permitted set the `vrf`.

Then you can easily permit *N* different source networks in `access-list 100` and *M* different destination networks in `access-list 101`.

Comment: Issue is I need to match against 2 ACL's. First ACL to match source, second ACL to match destination. If I combine them in extended ACL that match both at the same time, it will be too long.

Comment: @zaidwaqi If i understand that correctly, you need to match packets **FROM** a specific source **TO** a specific destination? As in `access-list 100 permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0`?

Comment: hi... that's correct. but I want to separate FROM and TO ACL. As in  **access-list 100 permit ip 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 any** and **access-list 110 permit ip any 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0**. Imagine I have 5 different IP to match for source, and 5 for destination. If I separate, the ACL length will only be 10 in total. If I combine, it will be 25 in length

Comment: @zaidwaqi Edited the question for a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

If you can't have a single access-list you can just use route-map numbers to have an "OR" condition.

```
route-map TEST permit 10
  match ip address 100
  set vrf TESTVRF
route-map TEST permit 20
  match ip address 110
  set vrf TESTVRF
```

Comment: Hi HampusLi. I'm aware of OR syntax. But my PBR requirement needs AND

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking you need to use object group instead.
route-map alone, it seems it's not achievable.

it depends on device you have, and it might support and might not support.
it may require ios upgrade or it may not support at all.

for example
object-group network src
1.1.1.0/24

object-group network dst
2.2.2.0/24